# Submit multiple dropdown menu at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two drop down menus and my goal to allow the user to pick the values; once they picked the items they can submit the values at once. However, for some reason I can't seem to figure out the best approach. To create drop down menu form I am using react `mui.com` library. Any help would be apricated, thank you.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';

const currencies = [
  {
    value: 'pakistan',
    label: 'Pakistan',
  },
  {
    value: 'India',
    label: 'India',
  },
  {
    value: 'jp',
    label: 'Japan',
  },
  {
    value: 'vit',
    label: 'Vietnam',
  },
 
];

const foodCourse = [
    {
      value: 'mainCourse',
      label: 'Main Dish',
    },
    {
      value: 'dessert',
      label: 'Dessert',
    },
    {
      value: 'drink',
      label: 'Drink',
    },
  ];

export default function CountiresDropDownMenu() {
  const [country, setCountry] = React.useState('pakistan');
  const [course, setCourse] = React.useState('mainCourse');
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    setLoading(true);
  }
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCountry(event.target.value);
    console.log("state", setCountry);

  };
  
  const handleFoodCourseChange = (event) => {
    setCourse(event.target.value);
    console.log("state", setCourse);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1.5, width: '25ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-select-country"
          select
          label="Country"
          value={country}
          onChange={handleChange}
          helperText="Please select a country"
        >
          {currencies.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-select-country"
          select
          label="Course"
          value={course}
          onChange={handleFoodCourseChange}
          helperText="Please select a course"
        >
          {foodCourse.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
        <LoadingButton
          onClick={handleClick}
          loading={loading}
          loadingIndicator="Loading..."
          variant="outlined"
        >
          Submit
        </LoadingButton>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a form. Your Submit button already has an onClick. So when the Submit button is clicked; handleClick() gets called.

```
function handleClick() {
    setLoading(true)

    // combine states into one object
    const data = {
        course,
        country
    }

    // submit data function
    // I like axios so this is my example
    axios.put("http://my.api/route", data)
      .then((res) => {
          // response from the api / server
          console.log(res)
          setLoaded(true)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          // if error we don't want to still be stuck loading so handle error here
          console.log(err)
          setLoaded(true)
      })

}
```

The above code is how I would submit the `country and course States` without a form. The only thing I added here was [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) to represent me making a http PUT request to a fake api route. Since you don't need any form validation and already have a `handleClick` function for your submit button; You can handle everything with `onClick`.

However if you wish to use the features of a `form` element google `form onSubmit`